# About greater sign and sigma

Tags: math-operators

What I want to write is

```
 if N+1 > N we do sigma (all the N) / the length of the array
```

For the greater sign I use

```
 If N+1 \textgreater N
```

But it's shown like this

```
 if N+1 >N
```

No space between the greater sign and N

And about sigma, I do `\sum N / Length of the array`

but doesn't seem right, the output is right but I get missing sign error

Comment: `\textgreater` is for text. You should write `$N+1>N$ do $\sigma N / \text{Length of the array}$`. Or if it is the sum, do `$\sum_N^{\text{Length of the array}}$`, yes the last one wont be pretty. :)

Comment: For `\text{}` (suggested by zeroth), you will need to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` or `\usepackage{amstext}` to the preamble of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand what you want to type. In my MWE I just show some possibilities and hope that one of them fits your needs.

The problem with the missing space you describe occurs due to  missing braces behind the command (`\textgreater{}`). You may read some LaTeX documentations like [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/dickimaw/dickimaw-novices.pdf) (2 MB) in order to understand, why this is happening.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fixes font size substitutions caused by xfrac
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
If $N+1 > N$ we do:

\[\sum_N^\text{Length of the array}\]
or:
\[\sum\frac{N}{\text{Length of the array}}\]
or in text maybe $\sum\sfrac{N}{\text{Length of the array}}$

If we want to use \verb+\textgreater+ we have to write it like $N+1$ \textgreater{} $N$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes it's `$\sum\sfrac{N}{\text{Length of the array}}$` thank you